# Calculate the m² price from m³ in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to convert an m³ price to m² price in Google Sheets

The price of a cubic meter is $2500 what would the price of a square meter be? Based on the size of the plank. 250cm x 100cm x 5cm

Or is there a built-in function within a spreadsheet that can make that calculation?

Comment: You can make any calculation in the spreadsheet. Just start your formula with `=`. E.g. In cell C1 you enter `=(A1 + B1)`. If value of cell A1 = 10, B1 = 20. The resulting formula will give you 30 in cell C1.

Comment: I know how to sum values, I need to convert an m³ price to m² price.

Comment: I'm not able to understand when you say convert m³ price to m² price ? Can you please provide some more insight to the statement ?

Comment: The price of a cubic meter is $2500 what would the price of a square meter be? Based on the size of the plank. 250cm x 100cm x 5cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to calculate total m3 volume:

```
=(250/100)*(100/100)*(5/100)
```

then you multiply it by price/m3 to get the price of unit:

```
=2500*((250/100)*(100/100)*(5/100))
```

and next, you just convert m3 to m2:

```
=(2500*((250/100)*(100/100)*(5/100)))^(2/3)
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OvD79YH3E6WckGNGURdnYrSlxttZvah2xxO9M1i_3ws/copy)

Answer (score 1):

As far I remember maths

```
Price (per m³) = $2500
Price (per m) = Cube root of (2500)
Price (per m²) = Square of (Cube root of (2500))
```

Suppose cell A1 contains price in per m³.
Hence, the formula in google sheet will be something like below:

```
=(A1 ^ (2/3))
```

You can use caret `x^y` symbol to x raise to power y.

I hope this will help you to create your formula.